# Python - Search a list of a group strings in text file

Tags: python, python-re, txt

I want to search a list of group of strings inside a text file (.txt or .log).

1. it must include group A or B (or CDE..).
2. group A OR B each words need in the same line but not near by. (eg. ["123456", "Login"] or ["123457", "Login"] if in the same line then save it to a new txt file.

Some of example output line:

```
20221110,1668057560.965,AE111,123457,0,"Action=Account Login,XXX,XXX",XXX,XXX
20221110,1668057560.965,AE112,123458,0,"Action=Account Login,XXX,XXX",XXX,XXX
20221111,1668057560.965,AE113,123458,0,"Action=Order,XXX,XXX",XXX,XXX
```

below is my code:

```
import os, re
path = "Log\\"
file_list = [path + f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.log')]


keep_phrases1 = ["123456", "Login"]
keep_phrases2 = ["123457", "Login"]

pat = r"\b.*?\b".join([re.escape(word) for word in keep_phrases1])
pat = re.compile(r"\b" + pat + r"\b")
pat2 = r"\b.*?\b".join([re.escape(word) for word in keep_phrases2])
pat2 = re.compile(r"\b" + pat2 + r"\b")
print(pat2,pat)

if len(file_list) != 0:


    for infile in sorted(file_list):
        with open(infile, encoding="latin-1") as f:
            f = f.readlines()
            for line in f:
                found1 = pat.search(line)
                found2 = pat2.search(line)
                if found1 or found2:
                    with open(outfile, "a") as wf:
                        wf.write(line)
```

It's works for me but not easy to add more group of words. And I think the code is not good for understand?

My problems is How can I simplify the code?
How can I easier to add other group to search? e.g. ["123458", "Login"] ["123456", "order"] ["123457", "order"]

Comment: Everything that's repeated (`pat = r"\b...`, `pat = re.compile...`) can be put in a function, and patterns can be put in a dictionary. If you put the `found`s in a holder (a list for example), you can use `any` instead of `if found1 or...`.

Comment: Sorry, How to put in dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, re
path = "Log\\"
file_list = [path + f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.log')]
```

All *keep_phrases* in a container, I choose a dictionary but since they are identified by order, it could have been a list:

```
keep_phrases = {'keep_phrases1': ["123456", "Login"], 'keep_phrases2':["123457", "Login"]}

# Alternative, a list would work:
# keep_phrases = [["123456", "Login"], ["123457", "Login"]]
```

Now let's generate a list with the compiled patterns:

```
def compile_pattern(keep_phrase):
    pat = r"\b.*?\b".join([re.escape(word) for word in keep_phrase])
    pat = re.compile(r"\b" + pat + r"\b")
    return pat

patterns = [compile_pattern(keep_phrases[keep_phrase]) for keep_phrase in keep_phrases.keys()]

# if keep_phrases had been a list, we would do
# patterns = [compile_pattern(keep_phrase) for keep_phrase in keep_phrases]
```

Finally, we look for matches for every pattern and if we get any finding, we write to file.

```
if len(file_list) != 0:
    for infile in sorted(file_list):
        with open(infile, encoding="latin-1") as f:
            f = f.readlines()
            for line in f:
                findings = [pat.search(line) for pat in patterns] # can do this because there's a list with patterns
                if any(findings):
                    with open(outfile, "a") as wf:
                        wf.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this. I read the whole file in a string to make code  fast and readable, findall will return a list with all matching lines for the file.
If memory is a problem the pattern also works on individual lines:

```
import re

file_list=["sit.txt"]

keep_phrases=[["123456", "Login"],["123457", "Login"]]

pat = [r"(?:.*?(?:" + p1 + r"\b.*?"+p2+r".*?(?:\n|$)))" for p1,p2 in keep_phrases]
pat= r"|".join(pat)

for infile in sorted(file_list):
    with open(infile, encoding="latin-1") as f:
        text=f.read()
        print(re.findall(pat,text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex

```
def match_words(line, words):
   return all(word in words for word in line)

with open(infile, encoding="latin-1") as f:
   f = f.readlines()
   for line in f:
      split_line = line.split(",")
      if any( match_words(split_line , word) for word in [keep_phrases1, keep_phrases2]):
         with open(outfile, "a") as wf:
            wf.write(line)
```